# Iterating in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is working fine until use Find_all()

```
name = soup.find('div', {'class':"tuple-title"}).select('div > p')[1].a.get_text(strip=True)
```

When I use find_all(), it says:

```
ResultSet object has no attribute 'select'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: You've told us what's happening, can you share what your question is? The error message is pretty clear in its prescription that you should be iterating the result set of `find_all()` if you need to operate on each item it returns.

Comment: Simply put: `find` returns a single item, `find_all` returns a list of items. So indeed you have to iterate the result of `find_all`: `names = [i.select('div > p')[1].a.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class':"tuple-title"})]`